# JavaScript passing a string into a method, which is an a attribute

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

```
myFunction('test')
```

I wish to set this on the onclick of an html element

```
<a href="#" onclick="myFunction('test')" >Link</a>
```

I need to capture this as a string and add it via JavaScript as an inner element. How can I capture this?

```
"<a href="#" onclick="myFunction('test')" >Link</a>"
'<a href="#" onclick="myFunction('test')" >Link</a>'
```

Neither seem to work.

Comment: I am adding the link to a div via Microsoft ajax templating

Comment: Can you post the 'myFunction' code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean you want to capture *'test'* as a string, and pass it as the parameter?
Try using backslahes before the single quotes surrounding *test*

```
<a href="#" onclick="myFunction(\'test\')" >Link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like...

HTML:

```
<a href="#" onclick="myFunction('test')" >Link</a>
```

SCRIPT:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction(userInput){ 
   document.getElementById('myNewHTMLElementID').innerHTML = userInput;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

i think

```
myFunction('test')
```

should be

```
myFunction(test)
```

if you want to use test as variable in the function.

The function call itself looks OK.